# Why does my custom directive not update when I derive the output from the bounded data?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

Basically I have a custom directive which has an isolated scope. I two-way bind a piece of data and given those data, I generate some output. For example, the data is two numbers 1 and 3. In the link() function of the directive I create a new array generating a sequential number between the two numbers. That new array I set in the scope. In the template, I do an ng-repeat on that new array. If I change those two numbers, the template does not seem to pick up the change. Here is a jsfiddle sample of what I am talking about:

http://jsfiddle.net/m2jf1Lw7/1/

You can see that when you click on change, nothing happens. If you change the template for my directive to be:

```
template: '<ul><li ng-repeat="d in data.list" my-button="d"></li></ul>'
```

changing "pages" to "data.list". If you click on change, you can see that the list will now change properly.

I am new to angularjs. I looked to see if there was a question similar to mine, but couldn't find any. My apologies if this is formatted or done incorrectly. Thanks for any insight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Nikos said, if you really want to detect the change of all the properties of the `data` variable, you need to use `deep watch` as following:

```
    ...
    link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
        scope.$watch(function () {
            return scope.data
        }, function () {
            var pages = [];
            for (var i = scope.data.list[0]; i <= scope.data.list[1]; i++) {
                pages.push(i);
            }
            scope.pages = pages;
        }, true); // The third parameter is true for deep watch
    },
    ...
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/m2jf1Lw7/2/).

Comment: Thank you for the sample code. New to angular so didn't know about deep watches or watch in general. Will try this tomorrow and if it works will select your answer.

Comment: This works perfectly for the sample I made, but had some problems with my actual code. In my code, for the template, I am using "d in pages track by $index" because my array has repeated values. It seems to break on that. Thanks for the help! Will probably try and solve this next problem or be back here with another question...

Answer (score 1):

The `'='` scope binding creates a watch on the variable you pass to it, in your case the `data`. So any change in the `data` triggers the watch and updates the isolated scope.

Watches on *objects* are by default using the equality, *not* deep watch: if the object reference remains the same, it is not considered changed, disregarding what happened to its contents. In your case you are changing the contents of `data`, but not the reference to `data` itself.

Same for `data.list`: When you watch `data.list` and then *set* `$scope.data.list` to a different value, the reference changes and the watch is triggered.